# How to express quantum field theory bounded by two Cauchy surfaces?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, causality

Imagine two 3 dimensional regions in space-time. The time coordinate is given in terms of the space coordinates.

$t=f_{0}(x,y,z)$ and $t=f_{1}(x,y,z)$. They also share a boundary. And everywhere except on the boundary where they are equal, $f_{0}(x,y,z)>f_{1}(x,y,z)$. i.e. the two regions bound 4D casual region.

Assume we can interpolate between one two regions with a parameter $u=0..1$ so this slices up time between the regions. Each slice defined by $t=f_u(x,y,z)$. (All slices have the same boundary). Now we define a wave function of a scalar field:

$$\psi_u[\phi]$$

and then $\psi_0[\phi]$ and $\psi_1[\phi]$ will be the wave functions of the scalar field for the initial and final surfaces respectively.

What hamiltonian equation will this satisfy? (The difference is the equation depends on the parameter $u$ instead of $t$).

My guess is something like:

$$\int_{region}dx^3 \left(\left(\frac{\partial f_u}{\partial u}\right)^{-1}\frac{\partial}{\partial u} + \frac{\delta^2}{\delta \phi^2(x)} + (\nabla \phi)^2\right)\psi_u[\phi]=0$$

And using a finite region like this, will that make some of the infinities arising from the functional derivative term go away? It looks like I might have missed out a factor corresponding to the area? As it has to integrate over the time derivative term now.

Edit: I think this is what I mean: https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0405006.pdf but without the boundary which seems unneccesary.

Comment: Are you asking about the Tomonaga-Schwinger equation? and where does your guess come from?

Comment: Yep. I just tried to work it out. Its the standard Klein-Gordon hamiltonian with a change of variables from t to u. But I might have made a mistake.